# ARDUINO Code in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, arduino

I'm new with this kind of projects and I'm trying to do my graduation project using Raspberry Pi 3 and vibration sensors. The sensor is **Piezo LDT0-028K** and I'm using **ADS1115** to convert analog to digital signs. The problem is the code, can I use this with rasp?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post text, not images of text. Your code is it is would not compile, you are using some library for `Serial` that you don't include or declare. Do you want to emulate a serial on a generic I/O port?

Answer (score 1):

No

Not only is code on the Pi written differently - the Pi has no analog hardware

Comment: But using a converter and  different codes?

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino pages at [Arduino creator](https://create.arduino.cc/editor) let you write Arduino style sketches and run them on a Raspberry Pi. There's some code you have to install on your Raspberry to get that stuff working. Start at [Arduino device manager](https://create.arduino.cc/devices/) to define your Raspberry and download the code you need.

Note: that won't solve your problem. The Raspberry Pi doesn't have ANY analog input without adding an external device like and Arduino or an MCP3008 (ADC chip). Running an Arduino connected by USB is a perfectly sane thing to do and fully supported.

Comment: Yes, I'm using i2c ads1115 that can do the same thing as MCP3008 (I think). But with ADC chips, I can do it, that is what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: Use GPIOzero with a python program to read those sensors.